# When removing words from a string, will a regex be faster than iterating over a list of words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

Right now, I am using this technique to remove unwanted words from a search:

```
IGNORED_WORDS.each { |e| params[:query].gsub!(e,'') }
```

My coworker tells me that a regex replacement will be faster. Is this true, and if so, why?

Comment: Depends on the situation. Just test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using regex, you would be combining all the ignored words to into a single regex using `Regexp.union`, and two reasons come to mind why using that may be faster.

1) There is no iteration necessary within Ruby. Regex match has to look through the alternatives within the single regex in question, but that is done by the Oniguruma regex engine implemented in C. That is faster than iterating for each ignored word in Ruby with your solution.

2) Since you will be using a single regex that has all the words as the alternatives, a match at a particular position stops once it succeeds with some alternative, and the other alternatives within the ignored words list will not be matched against at that position.

And 2) means that you can improve the speed by rearranging the ignored words in the order of likelihood to appear in your text.

**Edit** Sorry, 2) may not make much sense as why it is faster than the other method because in your other method, gsub! will remove the matched word from the original string, so the substring that was in that position will not be matched against the words to follow. In this respect, there should be no difference. However, if you are doing match without replacement, for example for counting the ignored words etc., then the regex method is faster in this respect too.

Answer (score 2):

As @sawa just said, a faster way to find any of your `IGNORED_WORDS` (if the array is large) is to do something like:

```
# just compile the regexp once, then use it as many times as you want
IGNORED = Regexp.union(*IGNORED_WORDS)

# then inside a method somewhere...
string.gsub!(IGNORED, '')
```

I don't know how smart the Oniguruma regexp engine is, but a good DFA-based engine will compile a regexp like that into a state machine which makes a single linear pass over `string` (never backtracking). If it compiles the regexp straight to native code, all the better (but Oniguruma doesn't -- it uses bytecode internally). For tasks like this, a DFA-based engine will go like stink -- no explicit string manipulation calls will touch it.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like naïve Regexes are any faster:

```
require "benchmark"

IGNORED_WORDS = ["foo", "bar"]

def regex
  my_string = "I foo'd her right in the bar last night!"
  IGNORED_WORDS.each { |e| my_string.gsub! Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(e)), '' }
end

def non_regex
  my_string = "I foo'd her right in the bar last night!"
  IGNORED_WORDS.each { |e| my_string.gsub!(e, '') }
end

puts "With regex:    ", Benchmark.measure { (1..100000).each { regex } }
#   1.750000   0.010000   1.760000 (  1.780110)
puts "Without regex: ", Benchmark.measure { (1..100000).each { non_regex } }
#   1.580000   0.000000   1.580000 (  1.592312)
```

In this case, creating a `Regex` instance from each word in your list of ignored words is incurring additional overhead, while using `gsub` requires only the original string.

However, if you knew all ignored words had a pattern that you could write a custom regex for, you could avoid looping over the `IGNORED_WORDS` array - which would definitely be faster. (`O(1)` instead of `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of `IGNORED_WORDS`, to be precise.)

Comment: If you use regexps like this, it will naturally be slow. There's a way which is much faster if `IGNORED_WORDS` is large... let me just write up an answer.